# what is the difference between these two

Tags: javascript

I'm very new to js so I'd appreciate some help. I have two blocks of code that I think should work identically but don't. Can someone explain how they're different? It looks like in the first piece of code, the parser enters the function directly.

```
function embedGameSwfAfterReg() {
    embedGameSwf("{$swfLocation}", "100%", "100%", {$flashVars});
}
API.registerOnload(embedGameSwfAfterReg())
```

and

```
API.registerOnload(function() {
    embedGameSwfAfterReg("{$swfLocation}", "100%", "100%", {$flashVars});
});
```

Comment: What do you think `()` means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first code block, you're registering the result of the `embedGameSwfAfterReg` function (undefined) as the onload function (`()` means you're evaluating the function).  Remove the parentheses to have the `embedGameSwfAfterReg` function itself registered:

```
API.registerOnload(embedGameSwfAfterReg)
```

Answer (score 0):

This

```
API.registerOnload(embedGameSwfAfterReg())
```

runs `embedGameSwfAfterReg`, and then passes the return value (`undefined` since it doesn't return a value), to registerOnLoad

you want

```
API.registerOnload(embedGameSwfAfterReg)
```

which passes the function itself to `registerOnload`

Functions are objects in Javascript and can be passed directly by their names.  When you add the parens, it instead runs the function and passes the result.

Answer (score 0):

```
function embedGameSwfAfterReg() {
    embedGameSwf("{$swfLocation}", "100%", "100%", {$flashVars});
}
API.registerOnload(embedGameSwfAfterReg)
```

and

```
API.registerOnload(function() {
    embedGameSwfAfterReg("{$swfLocation}", "100%", "100%", {$flashVars});
});
```

would work the same way.
The difference is **()** which you have put with `embedGameSwfAfterReg` function in the first case
It actually calls the function there only but its different in the 2nd case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm asssuming that the second example should be

```
API.registerOnload(function() {
    embedGameSwf("{$swfLocation}", "100%", "100%", {$flashVars});
});
```

If so, then the difference is quite big.  In the first case, the `embedGameSwfAfterReg` function is invoked and the `embedGameSwf` is called when you register.  This is probably not what you want since the the return value of the function is `undefined`.

In the second case, the anonymous function is not invoked until later when the `registerOnLoad` event is raised. This is probably what you want.

Answer (score 0):

API.registerOnload() takes a callback function as parameter, therefore you only have to pass in the function name as reference, otherwise the function is directly getting called when the code runs.

```
// Correct form is:
API.registerOnload(embedGameSWFAfterReg)
```

Your second sample already is an anonymous function that is handled like an function callback and therefore evaluated when API.registerOnload(callback) is calling the reference with `callback()` somewhere inside it's code.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**
First piece of code do nothing, because embedGameSwfAfterReg doesn't have a return statement. Probably it could even end up with an error if API.registerOnload doesn't accurately check its arguments before execution.

Second piece of code creates an anonymous-function that is passed as an argument to API.registerOnload method which (as far as I can see from method name) runs functions during an Onload event.

**Long answer:**
In the first piece of code you declare a new function named embedGameSwfAfterReg which  resists in global-scope of your code:

```
function embedGameSwfAfterReg() {
  // calls embedGameSwf function
}
```

after, you execute defined function and pass the result to registerOnload method of an object named API:

```
API.registerOnload(embedGameSwfAfterReg());
```

As you probably mentioned, declared function embedGameSwfAfterReg has no return statement, so the result of its execution will be undefined. In other words

```
API.registerOnload(embedGameSwfAfterReg());
```

is doing the same as

```
embedGameSwfAfterReg();
API.registerOnload();
```

so eventually it calls API.registerOnload() WITHOUT any arguments passed!

Second piece of code creates an anonymous function (*functions are specific objects in JS, which can be passed to other functions/methods, have its own methods and executed*). Then it passes created function (or better say a reference to the function) to registerOnload - method of an object called "API".

You should read topics about Objects, Function-type, scopes, anonymous functions and closures in JS. I would advise [Mozilla JavaScript guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions)

Also feels free to play with [a simplified example at jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sergei_s_r/zPC62/)  which gives some practical hint on anonymous functions in JS.